# PHP Post data with Fsockopen

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

I am attempting to post data using fsockopen, and then returning the result.
Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$data="stuff=hoorah\r\n";
$data=urlencode($data);

$fp = fsockopen("www.website.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "POST /script.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.webste.com\r\n";
    $out .= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n';
    $out .= 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data) . '\r\n\r\n';
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

It is supposed to echo the page, and it is echoing the page, but here is the script for script.php

```
<?php
echo "<br><br>";    
$raw_data = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];  
 parse_str( $raw_data, $_POST );

//test 1
var_dump($raw_data);
echo "<br><br>":
//test 2
print_r( $_POST );  
?>
```

The outcome is:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 02 Mar 2010
>   22:40:46 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3
>   (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
>   Content-Length: 31 Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>         string(0) "" Array ( )

What do I have wrong? Why isn't the variable posting its data?

Comment: I cant use curl because this will be Open Source

Comment: "Curl is free and open software" Curl is licensed under the MIT/X license.

Comment: you cant expect everyone (even people with shared hosting) to want and get curl

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but shouldn't there only be one \r\n after each of the header fields? With the exception of the last one of course...

Comment: shouldn't '\r\n' be "\r\n" ? Do those escape things work in single quotes

Comment: ive attempted both, still nothing.

Comment: Do you have `always_populate_raw_post_data` enabled? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Comment: that was off, turning it on now to see if that works.

Comment: If you can't use cURL binaries, you can try pURL, a pure PHP implementation of cURL.

Comment: You only have the double \r\n after the last header. You have it twice, after content-length: and connection:

Answer (score 20):

There are many small errors in your code. Here's a snippet which is tested and works.

```
<?php

$fp = fsockopen('example.com', 80);

$vars = array(
    'hello' => 'world'
);
$content = http_build_query($vars);

fwrite($fp, "POST /reposter.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Host: example.com\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "\r\n");

fwrite($fp, $content);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 1024);
}
```

And then at example.com/reposter.php put this

```
<?php print_r($_POST);
```

When run you should get output something like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Jan 2011 21:24:07 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Vary: Host
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

1f
Array
(
    [hello] => world
)
0
```

Comment: Why does it show "1f" and "0" at the end there? I get the same, but not quite sure.

Comment: it works but you have to change in fsockopen to fsockopen('www.example.com', 80); and in fwrite to fwrite($fp, "Host: www.example.com\r\n");

Answer (score 1):

At no point is `$data` being written to the socket. You want to add something like:

```
$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

Comment: I did that and still no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
$out .= 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data) . '\r\n';
$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out .= $data;
```

Comment: Try installing a packet sniffer on your server and see what headers are actually being sent to the server. Are they the same as what you're sending in php?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$data="stuff=hoorah\r\n";
$data=urlencode($data);

$fp = fsockopen("www.website.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "POST /script.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.webste.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out .= 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Some character escapes such as `\n` do not work in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Nice one Tamlyn, works great!

For those that also need to send get vars along with the url,

```
//change this:

fwrite($fp, "POST /reposter.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");

//to:

$query = 'a=1&b=2';
fwrite($fp, "POST /reposter.php?".$query." HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in reposter.php

```
$raw_data = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']; 
parse_str( $raw_data, $_POST );

print_r( $_POST );
```

Because,  the data wasn't in the `$_POST[]` variables but it was in the `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this technique it will help to call as many as pages you like all pages will run at once independently without waiting for each page response as asynchronous.

**cornjobpage.php //mainpage**

```
    <?php

post_async("http://localhost/projectname/testpage.php", "Keywordname=testValue");
//post_async("http://localhost/projectname/testpage.php", "Keywordname=testValue2");
//post_async("http://localhost/projectname/otherpage.php", "Keywordname=anyValue");
//call as many as pages you like all pages will run at once independently without waiting for each page response as asynchronous.
            ?>
            <?php

            /*
             * Executes a PHP page asynchronously so the current page does not have to wait for it to     finish running.
             *  
             */
            function post_async($url,$params)
            {

                $post_string = $params;

                $parts=parse_url($url);

                $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
                    isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
                    $errno, $errstr, 30);

                $out = "POST ".$parts['path']."?$post_string"." HTTP/1.1\r\n";//you can use GET instead of POST if you like
                $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
                $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
                $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
                $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
                fwrite($fp, $out);
                fclose($fp);
            }
            ?>
```

**testpage.php**

```
    <?
    echo $_REQUEST["Keywordname"];//case1 Output > testValue
    ?>
```

PS:if you want to send url parameters as loop then follow this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/41225209/6295712

Answer (score -1):

Curl is too heavy in some case, to use post_to_host():

```
//GET:
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, array(), $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head, 0);

//POST:
$arr_params=array('para1'=>'...', 'para2'=>'...');
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, $arr_params, $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head);

//POST with file:
$arr_params=array('para1'=>'...', 'FILE:para2'=>'/tmp/test.jpg', 'para3'=>'...');
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, $arr_params, $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head, 2);

//raw POST:
$tmp=array_search('uri', @array_flip(stream_get_meta_data($GLOBALS[mt_rand()]=tmpfile())));
$arr_params=array('para1'=>'...', 'para2'=>'...');
file_put_contents($tmp, json_encode($arr_params));
$arr_params=array($tmp);
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, $arr_params, $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head, 3);

//get cookie and merge cookies:
$arr_new_cookie=get_cookies_from_heads($ref_arr_head)+$arr_old_cookie;//don't change the order

//get redirect url:
$str_url_redirect=get_from_heads($ref_arr_head, 'Location');
```

post to host php project location: http://code.google.com/p/post-to-host/

Answer (score -2):

Is using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and option?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for refresh, but for people who still have problem like this, change HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 and it will work.