# Retrieve data from a website automatically

Tags: web-services, authentication, web-applications, automation

Sorry if this sounds like a beginner question, I have to retrieve some data from http://admissions.giki.edu.pk/confirmfee.php but it turns out that you need to enter your admit card number for that. Is there a way I can automatically enter a huge amount of numbers and access the data? If this question is not clear enough, let me know.

Comment: Is the program your going to run written in PHP?

Comment: Yes! See I'm an Android developer so I dont have much idea about web services. Unfortunately I was given this project which I have no idea how to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form via $_POST. Of course you can create a form that has a action=? to the page directly, if you are just trying to get one value. If you are wanting to pull data remotely...

fsockopen() will do what you want if your good at HTTP/1.1

curl() will also work (and is a bit more user-friendly), but its slightly slower.

Ex; with fsockopen()

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609497/1377321

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know what you're talking about, I've never dealt with php before. Could you elaborate it more? Thanks.

Comment: Might recommend you try some basic things first with PHP fsocketopen, like reading a single page, before doing complicated stuff. POST is definitely not easy for someone new to PHP.

Comment: Okay I'll look for tutorials for fsocketopen online. Thank you!