# HTTP POST from PHP, without cURL

Tags: php, post, web

I am using the example function given in [this post](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/):

```
<?php
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
?>
```

I also tried a similar approach using `file_get_contents()`, like this:

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>
      "Accept-language: en\r\n".
      "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'content'=>http_build_query(
        array(
            'arg1'=>'arg_data_1',
            'oper'=>'get_data',
            'arg2'=>'arg_data_2',
            'id_number'=>'7862'
        ),'','&'
    )
));

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$refno = file_get_contents('/path/to/script/script.php',false,$context);

var_dump($refno);
```

With both these scripts, the response from the server script is the same, and it is the TEXT of the `script.php`.  The code of the server script is never begin executed, and the text content (the PHP code) of the script is being returned to the original script.

A little strange that it doesn't return all the text, but just certain pieces...  I tried making a test script (`test.php`) that just contains:

```
<?php
echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
?>
```

but that doesn't return anything from the POST request, so I didn't include that.  The `script.php` is a must longer script that does a lot of logic and MySQL queries then returns a JSON object.

The desired output will be to have the PHP code execute and return a JSON object (the way it works with ajax).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're simply reading the file locally - you're bypassing the webserver completely, so the PHP code isn't being processed into finished content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367458/php-post-data-with-fsockopen

Comment: I had run into a problem with curl and accessing the scripts on my local machine.  It looks like it was the same problem as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying access script localy.
You must call it like any other external script like

```
$refno = file_get_contents('http://yourhost/path/to/script/script.php',false,$context);
```